# SQL Reporting Services Report Manager cannot be accessed by IP on the local computer

Tags: sql-server, ip-address, internet-explorer, ssrs

I have set up SQL Express 2012 with Advanced Services on a test machine. The requirements are that ReportServer should run on a dedicated IP address and port. So I went to Reporting Services Configuration and set both Web Service and Report Manager to use 192.168.1.114 and port 3080 (I removed "All unassigned" entry, so 192.168.1.114:3080 is all that's left).

I am aware of the permission issues for SSRS when accessing from Internet Explorer, so I locally ran IE as Administrator to add all the other users and roles.

I can access the Report Manager if I enter URL:

```
http://user-pc:3080/Reports
```

but if I try to access it by IP:

```
http://192.168.1.114:3080/Reports
```

I receive an error:

```
User 'user-PC\user' does not have required permissions. 
Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted 
and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.
```

In both cases I am accessing the URL from Internet Explorer on the local machine, and IE is launched "As Administrator". The user 'user-PC\user' is a local administrator.

**What's going on there? Why do I have enough permissions to access the Report Manager using computer name, but not enough permissions to access it by IP?**

Comment: Does that user have access in SQL? Is that the user you picked when it forces you to add a local user during setup?

Comment: 'user-PC\user' is the same user account which was used to install SQL Server, and I see that 'user-PC\user' has sysadmin role in SQL Server and also it is mapped to both ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB.